# Processing Java code setLabel Error with Arraylist

Tags: java, processing

I made an array from a text file then split it into 3 more arrays after it detects something. Then it would skip the first element then add whatever is after into 1/3 arrays. The problem is when I use .setLabel(btn1Array.get(0)) it says the function "setLabel()" expects parameters like: "setLabel(String)" but I thought the arraylist is already a string. This is a snip of my code

```
void setup() {        // same as Ardunio program

  String[] settings = loadStrings("settings.txt");             // Converts each line from the text file into strings of code
                                                       
  List btn1Array = new ArrayList();                       
  List btn2Array = new ArrayList();
  List btn3Array = new ArrayList();


  for(int i = 0; i< settings.length; i++){                                            // Reads entire text file
    String currentLine = settings[i];
    if(currentLine.startsWith("btn")){                                                // Reads textfile, if line starts with "btn" does something
        String  stringArray[] = currentLine.split(" ");                               // Splits string into different elements if there is a space
        String newArr[] = Arrays.copyOfRange(stringArray, 1, stringArray.length);     // Skips first element and copys other elements into a new array
        String value = String.join(" ", newArr);                                      // Joins other elements into one string if there is a space between 2 elements (ie: Blue Lights)
        
        if(currentLine.startsWith("btn-1")){                                          // If line starts with btn-1
            btn1Array.add(value);                                                     // Add element into last place of btn1Array
        } else if(currentLine.startsWith("btn-2")){                                   // If line starts with btn-2
            btn2Array.add(value);                                                     // Add element into last place of btn2Array
        } else if(currentLine.startsWith("btn-3")){                                   // If line starts with btn-3
            btn3Array.add(value);                                                     // Add element into last place of btn3Array
        }   
      } 
  }
  
  size(700,900);                                         // Window size, (width, height)
  printArray(Serial.list());                             // prints all avalible serial ports
  port = new Serial(this, "COM13", 9600);                 // COM where arduino is connected
  
  font1 = createFont("Arial Black",30,true);             // Arial, 30 point, anti-aliasing on
  font2 = createFont("Arial Black",23,true);             // Arial, 23 point, anti-aliasing on
  
  cp5 = new ControlP5(this);
  
  Button1 = cp5.addToggle("button1")                              // Sets button1
    .setLabel(btn1Array.get(0))
```

This is my textfile

```
------- NAME OF BUTTON 1 -------

btn-1-name: Lights

------- BACKGROUND COLOUR OF BUTTON 1 -------

btn-1-BGcolourR: 255
btn-1-BGcolourB: 165
btn-1-BGcolourG: 0

------- FOREGROUND COLOUR OF BUTTON 1 -------

btn-1-FGcolourR: 255
btn-1-FGcolourB: 100
btn-1-FGcolourG: 0
```

However I get this error

"The method setLabel(String) in the type Controller is not applicable for the arguments (Object)"

I dont know why I get this error since what I pulled should be a string

Comment: You really want to learn about Java generics `List whatever = new ArrayList()` is sooo outdated, and thus not doing what you expect it to do. You probably want `List<String> whatever = new ArrayList<>()` . In your code, the compiler thinks that your lists contain objects of the type `Object`. It doesnt matter that you add Strings at runtime. The COMPILER doesn't know that.

Comment: So, the real answer could be: study some java basics for a while. Read a decent book or tutorial, and LEARN how things work, before starting to invent your own syntax and semantics and finding out that you do not make progress with trial and error when you lack knowledge about all the basic things.

Comment: And then: give your variables meaningful names. `btn1Array" ... why call it an array when it is a list?

Comment: [A simple Answer for  that](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/First_steps/What_is_JavaScript)

Answer (score 2):

You need to explicitly tell Processing that the things you are storing the ArrayList are Strings. Otherwise it assumes they are generic "Objects".

Three potential fixes (choose one):

1. Let Processing know that the type of everything stored in the ArrayList is a string. You do this when you first declare the variable:

```
ArrayList<String> btn1Array = new ArrayList<String>();
```

You do this by putting the type in angle brackets after `ArrayList`. You can see this with the `Particle` type in the example in [the docs for ArrayList](https://processing.org/reference/ArrayList.html)

2. You can cast the value as a String when you pull it out of the ArrayList. This tells Processing that even though it assumes it's an Object, you know it should be a string:

```
.setLabel((String) btn1Array.get(0))
```

You do this by putting the type in parentheses directly before the value you want to cast.

3. You can use [StringList](https://processing.org/reference/StringList.html) instead of ArrayList.
   This is more a less a shortcut built in to Processing for doing #1 (creating a list of Strings).